# Overriding a variable in a loop in consul-template

Tags: templates, go, consul, consul-template

I'm using the following template in consul-template:

```
{{ range services }}
  {{ $server_name := .Name | replaceAll "_" "." }}
  {{ range .Tags }}
    {{ if . | regexMatch "server_name=" }}
      # found matching server_name in {{ . }}
      {{ $server_name := . | regexReplaceAll ".*=" "" }}
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
  # server_name = {{ $server_name }}
        acl host_{{ .Name }} hdr(host) -i {{ $server_name }}
        use_backend {{ .Name }}_backend if host_{{ .Name }}
{{ end }}
```

which produces

```
  # found matching server_name in server_name=geoserver.hello.org






  # server_name = geoserver.dev.hello.org
        acl host_geoserver_dev_hello_org hdr(host) -i geoserver.dev.hello.org
        use_backend geoserver_dev_hello_org_backend if host_geoserver_dev_hello_org
```

where `.Name` is `geoserver_dev_hello_org` and there is a `server_name=geoserver.hello.org` tag. I expect that by the end of the `.Tags` range loop, `$server_name` should have value `geoserver.hello.org`, but it still has its original value of `geoserver.dev.hello.org`.

How can I make it so that the loop overrides `$server_name` (and exit the loop when the value is found)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a Go template range loop, are variables declared outside the loop reset on each iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674199/in-a-go-template-range-loop-are-variables-declared-outside-the-loop-reset-on-ea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner `$server_name` and outer `$server_name` are different variables. You can't set a variable from outer scope in Go templates: http://play.golang.org/p/0fuOmqXrSK.

You could try and rewrite your template to print the `acl` etc. part inside the inner `if` which would work unless you need to execute that part just once. Go templates are not designed as a scripting language for complex logic, it's a tool for showing pre-computed information. A `fmt.Printf` on steroids if you will. All logic including search and replacement should be in Go, it'll be faster, safer, easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: Thank you. In consul-template, I'm guessing I'd need to write a [plugin](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template#plugins) to in order to write Go code for that?

Comment: @ℝaphink Looking at their docs it seems like you can write a plugin in any language, not just Go. Also, now that I think of it, moving the part after the loop inside is not actually a bad idea, unless you need to ensure that it only prints once.

Comment: Well in that case actually, it wouldn't hurt if I printed a line for `server_name` as well as `.Name`, so I might actually do that.

Answer (score 6):

In a `consul-template` template, you can use [the scratch](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template#scratch) - a temporary key-value store available throughout the lifetime of a template.

Your code would look like this:

```
{{ range services }}
  {{ $server_name := .Name | replaceAll "_" "." }}
  {{ scratch.Set "server_name" $server_name }}
  {{ range .Tags }}
    {{ if . | regexMatch "server_name=" }}
      # found matching server_name in {{ . }}
      {{ $server_name := . | regexReplaceAll ".*=" "" }}
      {{ scratch.Set "server_name" $server_name }}
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
  # server_name = {{ scratch.Get "server_name" }}
        acl host_{{ .Name }} hdr(host) -i {{ $server_name }}
        use_backend {{ .Name }}_backend if host_{{ .Name }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: nice nice nice nice

Answer (score 1):

Since [Go 1.11 release](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.11#text/template) it's possible to modify variables via assignements within templates. So this is working now:

```
  {{ $v := "init" }}
  {{ if true }}
    {{ $v = "changed" }}
  {{ end }}
  v: {{ $v }} {{/* "changed" */}}
```

This version was [introduced](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/commit/60b846f4406ce87acec7c3c1de5d0725a54e4522#diff-76ed074a9305c04054cdebb9e9aad2d818052b07091de1f20cad0bbac34ffb52) to Consul Template with the [v0.25.1](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/releases/tag/v0.25.1) release.