# How do I assign variables within a conditional

Tags: go-templates

Given a `YAML` file and `go` templates, I can assign a variable with:

```
{{ $foo := "bar" }}
```

And I can use a conditional like:

```
{{ if eq $foo "bar" }} jim {{ else }} bob {{ end }}
```

How do I combine the two to assign the result of a condition to a variable?

I've tried:

```
{{ $foo := "bar" }}

{{ if eq $foo "bar" }}
{{ $foo = "jim" }} 
{{ else }}
{{ $foo = "bob" }}
{{ end }}
```

But `foo` remains `bar`

Comment: This kind of logic is generally best kept out of templates, either by doing the logic and passing the correct value in with the template data, or by adding a custom template function to do the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with Go 1.10 and earlier versions, template variables (identifiers) cannot be modified (there are "workarounds", see following link). They can be re-declared / shadowed in a(n inner) block, but once you are out of the inner block, the changes will not be visible. For details and workarounds, see [In a Go template range loop, are variables declared outside the loop reset on each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674199/in-a-go-template-range-loop-are-variables-declared-outside-the-loop-reset-on-ea/28674752#28674752)

Note that however Go 1.11 is about to be released [which will support this](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.11#text/template).

This will be a valid and working template code starting with Go 1.11:

```
{{ $v := "init" }}
{{ if true }}
  {{ $v = "changed" }}
{{ end }}
v: {{ $v }} {{/* "changed" */}}
```